# Java resize heap question

Tags: java, heap-memory

If there was a way to resize the heap by passing `Xmsn` to the argument array in main.
Could I be shown a small example of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not resize the amount of memory allotted to the Java Virtual Machine `(-Xmx)` once it's been started.  What you could do is launch *another* Java process from your main with the value you get from the args array.

Comment: No, you can use a property file, or some other external mechanism.  But you cannot change it for a Java process that has already started.

Comment: So how do I get around the OutOfMemory exception.

Comment: Thats a whole different question that you need to post, including context (memory settings, stack trace, etc).

Comment: If you are getting out of memory issue, first look at your code and see where you are hoarding so much data. Perhaps that needs to be broken up and handled incrementally.

Comment: I agree with @CoolBeans, but assuming your code can't be optimized further, then you just need to make sure it is started using the proper arguments as outlined in Amir's answer.  Often time it's helpful to create a little .bat or .sh script that wraps the command line java call and sets all the jvm arguments.